# Game Developing Resources

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

I would like to get into learning how to develop games. I already have an idea of what I would like to attempt, but even after looking around the internet, I am unsure of where to start, it all seems so overwhelming. I'd like to attempt at a 2d over-head camera shooter, but I can't seem to figure out what to write first, what needs to be done. It's not going to be a multiplayer game, so there is no need to worry about networking. To start, I just want something with a simple applet that accepts wasd and mouse movement. However, I know how to implement those things after I get the visuals to appear. I'm really sorry if this doesn't make much sense, my mind is busy trying to think of where to start.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Though an external site to stackoverflow, this is very good: [gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net) . A lot of pros are there to help you with specific problems.

Answer (score 2):

How about a book? [Killer Game Programming in Java](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/)?

You can download all the source code from the website if you don't want to buy the book. That should be a good start!

Chapter 4 takes you through writing a game named Worms, which is very similar to Snake on the old Nokia phones.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this Java based game engine - [MonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There have been some previous questions similar to this one. See if any of these help answer your question (or help to clarify what you want to learn).

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752930/getting-started-with-game-development
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429192/game-development-guideline
- [Learning about game development, any books recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532516/learning-about-game-development-any-books-recommended)
- [Getting started at Game Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377886/getting-started-at-game-development)
- [The Game vs The Game Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981370/the-game-vs-the-game-engine/4981536#4981536)
- [How to create a FPS game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288153/how-to-create-a-fps-game/288376#288376)

It really depends on what languages you are comfortable programming with. There are some very powerful tools for developing 3d games. For C# there is Unity3d, Java has JMonkeyEngine, etc. I have tried both of these, and they have pretty high learning curves. There are also some development kits based on existing game engines. For 2d games, there are even more game engines to choose from. Which language will you be using? There are probably already a lot of resources for making a game in that language.